# What is my Eclipse-RCP application storing in $HOME/.eclipse, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp

When I run my Eclipse RCP application, it creates a whole lot of directories in my `$HOME/.eclipse` directory. What is this?

I don't want the files there, how can I hinder them from getting there? The rational for this: the application must run very clean and only leave files at one specific location (not $HOME/.eclipse).

I'd figured it was controlled by `osgi.instance.area` so tried to set this to different values (a directory, @none, @noDfault etc...) but can't stop the application from creating directories in $HOME/.eclipse. -data and other arguments works as expected.

Comment: what are the directories created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system the only thing that is stored in .eclipse is the Equinox Secure Storage.  Here is the blurb on the doc page for that:

> By default, secure storage is located in your home directory. On Windows that typically resolves to "C:\Documents and Settings\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security". This location is selected to allow multiple Eclipse-based applications to share the same secure storage.
>
> If you would like to modify the location of the default secure storage, you can use the "-eclipse.keyring " runtime option. The  is a path to the file which is used to persist the secure storage data.

Here is the [online reference.](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-securestorage-options.htm)